# Facebook popup dialog available?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to show users custom message with a single OK button in a Facebook-style dialog box, say, in an iframe app? Is this dialog box available in the Facebook (Javascript) API?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that Facebook allows you to display dialogs outside the ones listed in the FB:Dialog documentation on their webpage.

However, this should be possible to implement yourself. Download a copy of the Facebook.js SDK, and look for the code where it draws the dialog. You could then use this wherever you want to draw as many Facebook-esque dialogs as you like!

**Edit:** This thread from the Facebook developers forum has some good stuff on already-developed FB.ui lightbox clones: [reuse facebook lightbox JS](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=92703)